# Заменить на 0 все элементы матрицы лежащие на главной диагонали и выше нее

Tags: java

Матрица создается, но элементы на 0 не изменяются. Можете помочь, не понимаю, в чем проблема.

```
// часть 1 - создаем матрицу n на n
        int n;
        Scanner con = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите количество строк и стобцов n = ");
        n = con.nextInt();
        if (n<=0){
            System.out.println("Упс! Что-то пошло не так, попробуйте снова");
            System.out.print("Введите количество строк и стобцов n = ");
            n = con.nextInt();
        }
        if (n==1){
            System.out.println("Это не подходитю. Введите больше");
            System.out.print("Введите количество строк и стобцов n = ");
            n = con.nextInt();
        }
        int[][] a = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                a[i][j] = n*i + j;//a[i][j] = n*i + j // просто заполняет массив по порядку числами , начиная с 0
            }
        }

        // часть 2 - выводит на экран начальную матрицу
        System.out.println("Начальная матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4d", a[i][j]);//"%4d" значит "4 пробела"
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


        // часть 3 - выводит на экран измененную матрицу
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Новая матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for(int j = 0; j <  a.length; j++) {
            for(int i = 0; i < a[j].length; i++) {
                a[i][j] = 0;
                System.out.printf("%10.2f %c", a[i][j], ' ');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

///////

```
public static void clearNE(int[][] a) {
        // часть 3 - выводит на экран измененную матрицу
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Новая матрица");
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (j <= i) {//i<=j – элементы расположены на и выше главной диагонали;
                    a[j][i] = 0;
                }
                System.out.printf("%4d %c", a[j][i], ' ');
            }
           // System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
       }
```

Comment: Поправьте теги. Это не Питон.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто поправьте 3ю часть своего кода на:

```
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Новая матрица");
    System.out.println("------");
    for(int j = 0; j <  a.length; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (j<=i){
                a[j][i] = 0;
            }
            System.out.printf("%4d %c", a[j][i], ' ');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

У вас там просто пара ошибок.

Если надо третью часть вывести в отдельную функцию, то надо:

```
// часть 2 - выводит на экран начальную матрицу
System.out.println("Начальная матрица");
System.out.println("------");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%4d", a[i][j]);//"%4d" значит "4 пробела"
    }
    System.out.println();
}

clearNE(a);  // И только вот эту одну строку вместо 3й части.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то долго голову ломала над тем, где у меня там ошибки))) И еще такой вопрос, можно ли 3 часть кода вставить в метод void clearNE(int[][] matrix) {} ? Я пыталась это сделать, но оно у меня работало и выбивало много ошибок.

Comment: Я добавила код к тому, что выше. Но я ,скорее всего, вообще не то сделала.

Comment: @НастяГрант Всё там правильно. поменяйте просто всю 3ю часть на `clearNE(a);`

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь, я немного не понимаю, как это сделать. Я же всю 3-ю часть вставила в этот метод, но мне ничего не выводит. Мне вывод только начальную матрицу и все, даже ошибки уже не выбивает.

Comment: @НастяГрант добавил в ответ, что надо сделать.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = j - элементы на главной диагонали
i> j – элементы расположены ниже главной диагонали;
i<j – элементы расположены выше главной диагонали;
i+j< n+1– элементы расположены над побочной диагональю;
i+j> n+1– элементы расположены под побочной диагональю;
```